# First page of PDF's uploaded to web server appearing blank

Tags: pdf, ftp

I've uploaded the pdf's to a client's web server (using the upload on a cpanel and filezilla), and the first page of each multi page pdf appears blanks.

http://red-rockfinancial.com/downloads/Critical%20Illness.pdf

The text is there as when you highlight and copy, you do copy the text, but I've tried everything I can think of I cant get the pdf's to upload.

It's worth noting that pdf's have been correctly uploaded to this site several times, however this particular "batch" of pdf is the only set having this issue. I've renamed, and resaved the files several times with no luck.

Comment: I just downloaded that PDF and the first page is there all right.

Comment: I've basically noticed that the error only occurs for me if I view the pdf in chrome ? can anyone else confirm?

Comment: In Chrome (using the integrated PDF viewer) I can confirm that the first page appears blank. But the first page really is weird...

Comment: Do you mean that there is something inherently weird about the page and that is what is causing it display like this? or that they way it's displaying is weird? Sorry just looking for some clarification.

Comment: See my answer. It looks like someone wants to test PDF processor limits here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PDF seems to be made to check out limits of PDF viewers.

PDFs have a page dictionary for each page. This dictionary has an entry **Contents** whose value is a stream or an array of streams describing the content of the page.

A part of the content of the page may be moved into a separate object, though, a so called form xobject, which merely is referenced from the page content. This allows the easy re-use of these content parts as such a xobject can be referenced from many pages. It also allows for grouping of content to allow for special transparency effects.

Form xobjects in their contents can again reference other xobjects.

The first page of your document uses this structure to the extreme, its content is

```
q Q q 0 0 595 841 re W n /Fm1 Do Q
```

i.e. it saves the current graphic state, sets a clip path around the border, includes form xobject **Fm1**, and restores the graphic state.

**Fm1** has the content

```
q Q q 0 0 595 841 re W n /Fm2 Do Q
```

i.e. it saves the current graphic state, sets a clip path around the border, includes form xobject **Fm2**, and restores the graphic state.

**Fm2** has the content

```
q Q q 0 0 595 814 re W n /Fm3 Do Q
```

...

**Fm29** has the content

```
q Q q 0 0 595 814 re W n /Fm30 Do Q
```

And finally **Fm30** has the actual page content.

The second page, on the other hand, immediately describes the page in its **Contents** stream.

PDF viewers do have certain limits concerning the nesting of xobjects and the more specifically the stacking of graphic states.

E.g. the nesting as observed above in essence means that the graphic state is saved 30 times, then the actual content is drawn, then the graphic state is restored 30 times. But the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) in section C.2 *Architectural limits* (which describes the minimum architectural limits that should be accommodated by conforming readers) gives a limit of *28* for ***q***/**Q** nesting.

Thus, a conforming PDF viewer does not need to support your PDF as it nests graphic state saving operations deeper than the specification requires it to support.